# Offline Form Checkbox List

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, offline

I have a form with 6 options that runs offline on a drive with no internet access. When a user clicks a checkbox, it places a heading in the textarea and likewise for the other options. If a checkbox is unselected, it removes the heading from the textarea. The user adds further details manually under headings, clicks Copy & Reset which copies it to clipboard. It is pasted elsewhere then.

Problem - when a checkbox is checked or unchecked, it resets all other free text that was added leaving headings only. I don't want this to influence additional data, only remove the specific heading if the option is unchecked.

I also want the last heading in the textarea to have a few line breaks after too. Help appreciated.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $(function() {
  $('input[name=activeOptions]').on('change', function() {
    var arr = $('input[name=activeOptions]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $('#Options').val(arr.join("\n\n\n.\n"));
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dis/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dis/checkboxoptions.js"></script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window.clipboardData.setData('text',
                          document.getElementById('Options').value                    
                         );

function ClipBoard1() 
{
    //create a new element, otherwise setting of range.text 
    //will change the form-fields values
    var dummy=document.createElement('textarea');

    //the range
   Copied = dummy.createTextRange();

   //set the text
   Copied.text = ".\n" +
                 "\+\+\+\+\+ CHECKS \+\+\+\+\+" +
                 "\n.\n" +
                 document.getElementById('Options').value + "\n\n" 
                 ;

   //expand the range to contain all contents
   Copied.expand('textedit');

   //Copy
   Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<body class="body">

<P>
<FORM name="Checks">

<div class="title">++++ CHECKS ++++</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
        <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell"><input type="checkbox" name="activeOptions" value='--Option 1--'>Option 1</div>
                <div class="divTableCell"><input type="checkbox" name="activeOptions" value='--Option 3--'>Option 3</div>
                <div class="divTableCell"><input type="checkbox" name="activeOptions" value='--Option 5--'>Option 5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell"><input type="checkbox" name="activeOptions" value='--Option 2--'>Option 2</div>
                <div class="divTableCell"><input type="checkbox" name="activeOptions" value='--Option 4--'>Option 4</div>
                <div class="divTableCell"><input type="checkbox" name="activeOptions" value='--Option 6--'>Option 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
<TEXTAREA NAME="Options" ID="Options" rows="15" cols="55"></TEXTAREA>
<p align=center>
<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard1();" class="copyreset">Copy & Reset</BUTTON>
<INPUT class="reset" type=reset value=Reset>
<p>
</DIV>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Bump...any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Does anyone have any suggested alternative to what I'm trying to do??